# Cognito Forgot Password : Username is also forgotten

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I implemented the forgot password flow in my react app, and it works find IF the user haven't forget his username. Problem now is he also forgot his username. In documentation, username is included as a required field.

```
var params = {
  ClientId: 'STRING_VALUE', /* required */
  Username: 'STRING_VALUE', /* required */
  AnalyticsMetadata: {
    AnalyticsEndpointId: 'STRING_VALUE'
  },
  ClientMetadata: {
    '<StringType>': 'STRING_VALUE',
    /* '<StringType>': ... */
  },
  SecretHash: 'STRING_VALUE',
  UserContextData: {
    EncodedData: 'STRING_VALUE'
  }
};
cognitoidentityserviceprovider.forgotPassword(params, function(err, data) {
  if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
  else     console.log(data);           // successful response
});
```

How to solve this issue?

Comment: Allow the user to reset by providing an email address?

Comment: @hephalump, but username is required. Username is forgotten. Do you have idea as to how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways you could potentially do this, one potential way would be to allow users to reset passwords using their email address.

This would be a two step process for your function. First, when the user submits their email address you will use the `ListUsers` API method with a filter applied on the `email` attribute. The response will include the username which you can then use in the second step which would be to send a password reset email.

You can read more about the `ListUsers` API method [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_ListUsers.html) in the AWS docs, and about searching for users using that method in the AWS docs [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/how-to-manage-user-accounts.html#cognito-user-pools-searching-for-users-using-listusers-api).

Comment: An alternative to this solution is enabling email address as an alias for your Cognito User Pool. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52572812/forgot-username-flow-for-aws-cognito/70255399#70255399 for more information.